# Couchbase SDK 3.0 enable/disable flush option from java

Tags: java, couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I'm trying to enable/disable bucket flush option using below code and it doesn't work. (SDK 3.0)

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Cluster cluster = Cluster.connect("host", "user", "password");
    cluster.bucket("bucketName").async();
    cluster.buckets().getBucket("bucketName").flushEnabled(true);
    cluster.buckets().flushBucket("bucketName");
}
```

Is there any other way to do it?
(If i enable the bucket option to flush, i am able to flush the bucket using above code.)

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a call to `updateBucket` which saves the modified settings:

```
public void setFlushable(Cluster cluster, String bucket, boolean flushable) {
  BucketSettings settings = cluster.buckets().getBucket(bucket);
  settings.flushEnabled(flushable);
  cluster.buckets().updateBucket(settings);
}
```

Comment: I tried adding the BucketSetting as u suggested but im facing below exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.couchbase.client.java.manager.bucket.EjectionPolicy` from String "noEviction": not one of the values accepted for Enum class: [valueOnly, fullEviction]
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.couchbase.client.java.manager.bucket.BucketSettings["evictionPolicy"])

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the SDK. What version of Couchbase Server, and what version of Couchbase Java SDK?

Comment: Also, can you confirm this is en "ephemeral" bucket?

Comment: I filed [JCBC-1647](https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/JCBC-1647) on the Couchbase Jira to track this issue.

Comment: im using Couchbase Server 5.5.6 and Couchbase Java SDK 3.0